# Ctrl-Shift-U requires *extra* U in Ubuntu 23.04 Cinnamon?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, unicode

I'm running a new install of Ubuntu 23.04 with cinnamon desktop 5.6.7

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> in a terminal does nothing unles the next character is another <kbd>u</kbd>; then the underlined `u` appears and I can enter the hex code.  If the second <kbd>u</kbd> is not typed, then the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> seems to be completely ignored.

Is this a bug or due to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> being grabbed for some other purpose in Cinnamon?

`echo Ctrl-Shift-U 2 6 3 A  #(without the spaces)`
just produces
`263A`.

`echo Ctrl-Shift-U U 2 6 3 A`
produces
`☺`.

The terminal emulator in the Cinnamon menu appears to be gnome-terminal even though the rest of Gnome is not being used, FWIW.